# What is the difference for locale: zh_CN, zh_CN.utf8 and zh_CN.UTF-8

Tags: utf-8, locale

For locale: zh_CN, zh_CN.utf8 and zh_CN.UTF-8, are they same?

- If they are same, why we need to use different name?
- If they are not, they should be used in what kind of situation?

Answer (score 0):

The one which doesn't specify a character encoding, well, doesn't. For the UTF8 character encoding, the variant `utf-8` is accepted, but the proper label for use in locale is `utf8`.